# How to get a external IP of VM running Kubernet Services

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, ip, virtual-machine

I have hosted Docker Images in a VM of Azure and I'm trying to access the Service outside VM. This is not working because of External IP is not generated for the Service.

After building the Docker image, I've applied yml file for creating Deployment and Service. My yml file looks as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: planservice-deployment
  labels: 
    app: planservice-deploy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: planservice-deploy
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: planservice-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: planservice-deploy
        image: planserviceimage
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: planservice-service
  labels: 
    app: planservice-deploy
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8086
  selector:
    run: planservice-deploy
---
```

After I ran the following command to look running services:

```
kubectl get pods --output=wide
```

This command returned all the running services and it's external IP information. But, when I saw the list, all the services are generated with blank external IPs.

How to set external IP for all the services, so that I can access my web services outside VM?

Comment: Does the existing answer solve your problem? If yes, you can accept it. Or you need to give more messages to describe what you want.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change `type` to `LoadBalancer`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: planservice-service
  labels: 
    app: planservice-deploy
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8086
  selector:
    run: planservice-deploy
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Comment: I did the same, but now the external IP is showing as `localhost`

Comment: i dont follow, what does that mean?

Comment: `type: NodePort` was generating nothing for external IP. `type: LoadBalancer` is generating 'localhost' as external IP

Comment: are you using aks or what?

Comment: well, this means you need to install `kubernetes cloud controller manager` and configure it to work with azure